# Prevent RST signal on port open in pySerial

Tags: python, serial-port, pyserial

Is it possible to begin serial port communications using pySerial without sending a reset signal?

I would like to not send a reset signal as I wish to communicate with an Arduino, which are reset by such a signal.

Comment: Is this article helpful? [DisablingAutoResetOnSerialConnection](https://playground.arduino.cc/Main/DisablingAutoResetOnSerialConnection/)

Comment: @kunif Looks like it might be, thanks